# Commit a transaction before calling a function in another EJB when using JTA

Tags: hibernate, ejb, jta

@Stateless(name = "A")
    public class A {

```
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @EJB
    private B serviceB;

    public void doSomeProcessA(List<AnyEntity> entities) {
        for (AnyEntity entity: entities) {
            //do some process.
            entityManager.persist(entity);
            serviceB.b(entity.getPrimaryKey());
        }

    }
}

@Stateless(name = B)
public class B {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    public void b (String id) {
        AnyEntity entity = entityManager.find(AnyEntity.class, id);

        try {
            //do some process

            entityManager.merge(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            sessionContext.setRollbackOnly();
        }
    }
}
```

this is my scenario. I want to persist entity first. And do some other changes on entity in b function. If any exception occurs, I want to make transaction rollback updates of entity but I want to keep persistent entity.

If I use this code as example, if any exception occurs, persist entities are not commited. If I use @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) on function, the process is not completed on service A, transaction is not comitted and writed to db, I cannot reach entity on service B. I cannot change b as b (AnyEntity entity) because of the business logic we use. What can I do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
 @Stateless(name = "A") 
 @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
 public class A {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction transaction;

    @EJB
    private B serviceB;

    public void doSomeProcessA(List<AnyEntity> entities) {
        for (AnyEntity entity: entities) {
          try {
            //do some process.
            transaction.begin();

            entityManager.persist(entity);

            transaction.commit();

            serviceB.b(entity.getPrimaryKey());
         } catch (Exception e) {
           try {
             this.transaction.rollback();
               } catch (IllegalStateException | SecurityException
                       | SystemException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}

@Stateless(name = B)
public class B {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;    

    @Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackOn = Exception.class)
    public void b (String id) {
        AnyEntity entity = entityManager.find(AnyEntity.class, id);
        //do some process    
        entityManager.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: as I know, there is no difference between my sample and your suggestion